# How can I save a session variable in the object?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I have the following Session variable: `Session["UserId"];`

How can I save this variable in the class and public variables? Something like this:

```
public class UserDC
{
    //public static Session UserId = Session["UserId"] 
}
```

I only want to call: `UserDC.UserId`.

Comment: Did you forget to use the concept of properties in C# (or VB)?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#: " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
public class UserDC
{
    public static string UserId
    {
        get
        {
            if(HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] != null)
                return HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"].ToString()
            else 
                return "";
        }

        set
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Session["Test"] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

In order to get a Session variable within a static property or static method, you must actually do the following because `HttpContext.Current` is static:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session
```

Comment: May want to add null reference checking.

Comment: When you save data to a static string UserId.
Does the data save in a session variable?

Comment: @user1180987:) "*When you save data to a static string `UserId`. Does the data save in a session variable?*". Makes no sense at all.

Comment: I have updated my answer according to what I think you were asking. Let me know if I didnt actually answer your question.

Comment: Can I insert the value directly into UserDC.UserId?

Comment: Yes you will be able to do UserDC.UserId = "test";

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string UserId
{
   get
   {
      return (string)Session["UserId"];
   }
}
```